# Error Access denied for user MySQL server?

Tags: c#-2.0

Error ERROR [HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver]Access denied for user (using password: YES) ERROR [HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver]Access denied for user  (using password: YES)

Comment: Could you please post more context for the question? as in what is the question and what is that you are trying to do etc

Answer (score 1):

Must be the semicolon in the password

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your MySql server allows remote connections. If not you'll have to bind the database and user to the remote IP(s) You also need to check the servers firewall settings to make sure 3306 (or whatever you're using) is allowed and that incoming connections are permitted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Connect your database using MySQL Workbench and try to run the following SQL statements:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES
    ON <database>.*
    TO '<user>'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '<password>';
SET PASSWORD
    FOR <user>@localhost = PASSWORD('<password>');
```

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else works, it might be something you mistyped in the password etc. To fix, connect as root, and reset the database permissions, password and flush the privileges:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES
ON <database>.*
TO <user>@localhost IDENTIFIED BY '<password>';

SET PASSWORD
FOR <user>@localhost = PASSWORD('<password>');

Flush Priviliges;
```