# Why this doesn't work: [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver]Access denied for user

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1045

So I know that there is a very similar question to this all over the web as well as stack overflow:

[Error Access denied for user MySQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539961/error-access-denied-for-user-mysql-server)

But my question I think is different. So I have set up a linked server and it works. I have the correct permissions set up for my IP's that I am using.  However the problem arises when our user "webuser@correctIP" tries to access it. Therefore, any user using window authentication is allowed to access it and works great. But any that are not using windows authentication are blocked.

However, I have tried all the common solutions such as setting up a strict password, changing security settings in Microsoft SQL Server etc. Nothing is working.

FYI: I am using this from Microsoft SQL Server 2008 -> mysql (through phpMyAdmin)

Comment: Doesn't make sense - MySQL knows nothing about windows authentication; it would likely be that the account returned by win authentication for the specific user doesn't have permissions in the MySQL database...

Comment: Yeah...agree it doesn't make sense but then why would the webuser (who is on an allowed IP) is blocked? And any user that has authentication isn't blocked. It might not be a windows thing...just trying to help those out who are reading :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I needed to do was to create a new user for my linked servers database(user for the mysql database).  Then I had to set up that user in the security section of the linked server properties box.  Once I created my new user and then chose "Be made using this security context:" and then added my newly created user and password it worked great.  If you have any question please just ask.  Thanks